# Copy only 1 row from a RecordSet (VB6)

Tags: vb6, recordset

I have a RecordSet in VB6 containing multiple rows. I have to copy the current (in a loop) row, and only this one, to another RecordSet (which will contain only that row).

The source RecordSet is retrieved from a SQL query. The destination, is only a container for local use.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of useful functions:

```
Public Function FilterRecordset(rsSrc As Recordset, sFilter As String) As Recordset
    Dim rsClone As Recordset

    Set rsClone = rsSrc.Clone
    rsClone.Filter = sFilter
    Set FilterRecordset = New Recordset
    Set FilterRecordset.DataSource = rsClone
End Function

Public Function CloneRecordset(rsSrc As Recordset) As Recordset
    With New PropertyBag
        .WriteProperty "rs", rsSrc, Nothing
        Set CloneRecordset = .ReadProperty("rs", Nothing)
    End With
End Function
```

These work best on client-side ADO recordsets.